# salesforce apex - string must be 6 digits and numeric only

Tags: if-statement, apex, apex-code

in this apex code the expected output was not getting the question is
Take a string type of variable

```
string pincode = '500038';
```

- Pincode must be exactly 6 digits, if the number of digits not equal to 6 then print **"Pincode must be 6 digits"**
- Pincode must be numerics only, if user enters alphabets then show error message **"Pincode must be numerics only"**

I tried this code

```
    string pincode = '500038';
    if (pincode.isNumeric()) {
     system.debug('Pincode must be numeric only');
       if (pincode.len == 6) {
    system.debug('Pincode must be 6 digits');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will resolve your problem, in first condition we are checking pincode in numeric or not and in sub condition we are checking length of pincode is 6 or not and at last in else condition we will be printing the msg if pincode is not numeric.
.

```
string pincode = '500038';
if (pincode.isNumeric()) {
    system.debug('Pincode is be numeric only');
    if(pincode.length() != 6) {
        system.debug('Pincode must be 6 digits');
    }
    if(pincode.length() == 6){
        system.debug('Pincode is numeric and has 6 digits::'+pincode);
    }
}else{
    system.debug('Pincode contains other characters then number::'+pincode);
}
```